# Save last queried keyword into array or db to show last

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to show the last 10 search word. So save it into an array wouldn't the best choice because after a refresh I will lost all data. And Session is also bad because it is unique to each browser. So DB but how to realize it any advice?

Only 10 words should be saved and if a new word is added the oldest should be deleted, so no more then ten word.

I would like to show all word separately in a html file thats it.

Comment: 10 keywords per user or 10 for all?

Comment: what efforts have you made at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

A key-value store might be what you want to look at.

For example **redis**.

http://redis.io/commands/ltrim

This shows exactly what you want to do.

```
LPUSH mylist someelement
LTRIM mylist 0 9
```

It would push one element to the list and then trim it back to 10 elements (0-9).

If you don't want to use a NoSQL database and just want to use an existing DBMS you should just follow default steps you would always to do write in to a database.

- start transaction
- count elements
- if it's already 10 -> delete the oldest
- save the new element
- commit transaction

Depending on your [isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) you might want to take care of different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 ways to store your result and I think there is no more:

1- Database

2- File

3- SESSION

4- Cookies

5- Array

Each has its pros and cons depends on your needs